I just started learning vue , i dont understand why index,html is not rendering anything
This works for a professor im following, but to me it doesnt i dont get it ,
index.html doesnt want to render anything , what am i missing? please help
https://data.netfinity.fr/d/6c6141c86a884dad90dc/
its just my seedbox with the flask and vue
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <!-- Include Vue.js (this can be from a CDN or local file) -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vue-router.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <router-link to="/">Početna stranica</router-link>
        <router-link to="/studentForma">Dodavanje studenta</router-link>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <script src="scripts/app.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>

it shows just routers but they are not links nor clickable, i left the full thing on my drive link
I dont understand why its not working , im pretty sure professor used the same and it worked for him

I recommend trying the official Vue CLI to scaffold a project. That will also not use the CDN.

You didn't set up the router properly, so router comps aren't rendered. There is supposed to be app.use(router) at some point
